# Little proof is needed

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Suppose that matrix **A** is real positive-definite and symmetric. Then there is **always** a matrix **T=BW** such that **$T^T A T$** is the identity matrix.  **W** is the diagonal matrix of the reciprocals of the square roots of eigen values of **A** (i.e. $W_{i,i}=1/\sqrt{\lambda_i}$ and **B** is the matrix that contains the corresponding eigenvectors of **A** as columns.

Also, some related question is, if we have $\phi$ being the matrix that contains the eigenvectors of a symmetric (possibly complex) matrix **C**. Can we be sure that $\phi^T\phi$ is always diagonal? or does this only hold for real matrix **C**

Thanks in advance

Comment: The entries of $\phi^T\phi$ are the scalar products of eigenvectors, hence the claim follows from their orthogonality (which holds par force if all eigenvalues are different). For correct scalar prodcut in the complex case, use $\phi^*$ instead

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a proof of the fact that $T^TAT$ is the identity matrix? The easiest proof is to give it a basis vector, and see what you get out on the other side. Also, we need to assume that if $A$ has repeated eigenvalues, then the corresponding columns of $B$ are orthogonal.